# Containment of user-specified type denied in class

Tags: c++, sfml, datamember, usertype

I have the **GameSettings** class.

*GameSettings.hpp*

```
class GameSettings
{
public:
    GameSettings();

    GameSettings loadSettings();
    void saveSettings(GameSettings const & GS);

    sf::VideoMode getVideoMode() const {return VMode;}
    bool isFullscreen() const {return fullscreen;}

private:
    sf::VideoMode VMode;
    bool fullscreen;

};
```

One *GameSettings* is contained in **Game** class (Game class is *Monostate*):

*Game.hpp*

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game() {};

    static void init();
    static void run();
    static void clean();
private:
    static sf::Window window;
    static GameSettings currentGS;  
};
```

Here is the implementation of init function (only implemented function in Game class yet):

*Game.cpp*

```
void Game::init()
{
currentGS.loadSettings();
sf::Uint32 style = currentGS.isFullscreen() ? sf::Style::Fullscreen : sf::Style::None | sf::Style::Close;
window.create(currentGS.getVideoMode(), "Name", style);

}
```

And I'm getting these errors:

**Game.hpp**:

(twice) *error C2146*: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'currentGS' - *Line 15*

(twice) *error C4430*: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int - *Line 15*

**Line 15**: `static GameSettings currentGS;`

**Game.cpp**

*error C2065*: 'currentGS' : undeclared identifier - *Lines 7, 8, 9*

*error C2228*: left of '.loadSettings' must have class/struct/union - *Line 7, 8, 9*

**These are only lines of init function ^**

Comment: Your code samples are incomplete. Are you including the headers for the classes you want to use? If you are, why don't your code samples reflect that?

Comment: oh yes, I didn't paste #include comands. In the end I found out that I forgot about one. Thanks a lot. Write it as answer and I'll mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted my comment as an answer and expanded it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code samples are incomplete. Are you including the headers for the classes you want to use? When you see an error like:

```
error C2065: 'currentGS' : undeclared identifier
```

or

```
error C2228: left of '.loadSettings' must have class/struct/union
```

It means that those variables or types (the `identifier`) are not known at this point in time -- and a common reason for that is you're not including a header file where the identifier is being declared. Make sure you're actually including the header files where you declare your variables and types.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting `const` at wrong place

update:

```
void saveSettings(GameSettings & const GS);
                                 ^^^^^
```

to:

```
void saveSettings(GameSettings const & GS);
                               ^^^^^
```